# Применение шаблонных типов в связных списках

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Проблема с шаблонами. Не понимаю в чем проблема, вроде пол-года назад писал тоже самое и все работало, а сейчас компилятор жалуется (на template... перед class Node...) Visual S вообще не запускает, а online компилятор указывает на эту строку, а именно :

> declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter

Не понимаю, что не так, объясните.

```
    template<typename T>
class List {
public:

    List();
    void push_back(T data);
private:

    template<typename T>
    class Node {
    private:
        T data;
        Node* pNext;
    public:
        Node(T data = T(), Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->pNext = pNext;
            this->data = data;
        }
    };
    Node<T>* head;
    int Size = 0;
};





template<typename T>
List<T>::List() {
    head = nullptr;
    Size = 0;
}

template<typename T>
void List<T>::push_back(T data) {
    if (head == nullptr) {
        head = new Node<T>(T data);
    }
    else {
        Node* current = this->head;
        while (current->pNext != nullptr) {
            current = current->pNext;
        }
        current->pNext = new Node<T>(data);
    }
    Size++;
}

int main()
{
    List<int> Data;
}
```

Comment: Зачем делать `Node` шаблоном?

Comment: @EOF чтобы разные типы данных узел мог хранить

Comment: Но дело в том, что узел должен знать тип указателя на следующий узел

Comment: Просто уберите `template<typename T>` перед `class Node`. Не нужен он там.

Comment: У вас в листе такой же параметр `T`, назовите второй по-другому. Или просто уберите, как уже подсказали

Comment: Понял, не знаю почему, но раньше так работало, я даже вспомнил, что изучал списки по обучению на youtube, видимо что-то изменилось с тех пор, ибо раньше компилятор не жаловался

Comment: @fofler msvc до сих пор [не жалуется](https://godbolt.org/z/sY4dda), но это не значит, что код валидный. Не советую изучать программирование на ютубе, надёжней использовать документацию. Можете дать ответ на собственный вопрос ниже, кстати

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
template <class T> class List {
public:
   List();
   void push_back(T data);
private:
    struct Node {
       T data;
       Node* next;
};
Node* head = nullptr;
```

Зачем вам `template<typename T>` перед вашим классом `Node`?

И когда вы создаете головной элемент `head`, он должен быть типа Узла, то есть просто `Node* head;`

Answer (score 1):

> declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter

Ну понятно же написано...

```
template<typename T>
class List {

    template<typename T>
    class Node {
```

Имена `T` одинаковые.